# A column named 'Item' already belongs to this DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to convert a `List` to a `datatable` with an extension method. Implementation is:

**Extension method**

```
public static class list2Dt
    {
        public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(List<T> items)
        {
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);

            //Get all the properties
            PropertyInfo[] Props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
            foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Props)
            {
                //Setting column names as Property names
                dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name);
            }
            foreach (T item in items)
            {
                var values = new object[Props.Length];
                for (int i = 0; i < Props.Length; i++)
                {
                    //inserting property values to datatable rows
                    values[i] = Props[i].GetValue(item, null);
                }
                dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
            }
            //put a breakpoint here and check datatable
            return dataTable;
        }
    }
```

**Controller**

```
var noDups = firstTable.AsEnumerable()
                            .GroupBy(d => new
                            {
                                name = d.Field<string>("name"),
                                date = d.Field<string>("date")
                            })
                            .Where(d => d.Count() > 1) 
                            .Select(d => d.First())
                             .ToList();

                        DataTable secondTable = new DataTable();
                        secondTable.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
                        secondTable.Columns.Add("date", typeof(string));
                        secondTable.Columns.Add("clockIn", typeof(string));
                        secondTable.Columns.Add("clockOut", typeof(string));

                        secondTable = list2Dt.ToDataTable(noDups);
```

I am getting this following error:

```
An exception of type 'System.Data.DuplicateNameException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: A column named 'Item' already belongs to this DataTable.
```

Above error is raised on line:

```
dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name);
```

Can someone find where problem lies.

Comment: You're problem is you've added 4 columns to your datatable, then you call toDataTable which tries to add all the columns

Comment: @BugFinder thats not the problem in this case, but it is pointless as OP then throws this away with the call to `ToDataTable` below it.

Comment: I missed that - good point

Comment: I may be wrong about this as correct terminology is not my strong suit, but I don't think this is an extension method :O

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ToDataTable` method is expecting a list of objects - most likely a list of simple DTOs or similar.

You are passing it a list of `DataRow` instances, of which that class has multiple [overloads of property `Item`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.item(v=vs.110).aspx) which means when you're trying to build up the new `DataTable` it will try to add multiple columns with the name `Item` which is invalid in a `DataTable`.

On way around this is to project `noDups` to a new object, rather than retain the `DataRow`:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string Date{get;set;}
}

var noDups = firstTable.AsEnumerable()
                        .GroupBy(d => new
                        {
                            name = d.Field<string>("name"),
                            date = d.Field<string>("date")
                        })
                        .Where(d => d.Count() > 1) 
                        .Select(d => {
                              var first = d.First();
                              return new MyClass()
                                 {
                                     Name = (string)first["name"],
                                     Date = (string)first["date"]
                                 }
                         })

                         .ToList();
```

Comment: Good work. Although it is giving me the correct output I'm still confused on "of which that class has multiple overloads of property Item which means when you're trying to build up the new DataTable it will try to add multiple columns with the name Item which is invalid in a DataTable."

Comment: @RehanKhan I purposly linked that sentence to some docs - did you follow it, read & understand? Alternatively, just step through your code as it was, and it should be clear.